# Upload more images from react-native app to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upload multiple images from react-native to firebase. The way I go about this is by using [expo image picker multiple - by monstrodev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-image-picker-multiple) ( see snack.io [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@monstrodev/expo-image-picker-multiple-full-example) )

I've managed to get it to work, and managed to be able to choose multiple photos from the 'improvised' camera roll. They load fine in the add screen, but I cannot find a solution on how to upload them properly.

```
        export default function Add(props) {

        const [name, setName] = useState("");
        const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null);



        const uploadImage = async () => {
        const uri = photos[0].uri; // -> uri is like this because 'media' is an array with objects inside that contain name, type, and uri each, and I only need uri of each oject.
        const childPath = `data/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
        console.log(childPath);
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const upload = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(childPath)
            .put(blob);

        const uploadProgress = snapshot => {
            console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
            };


            const uploadComplete = () => {
                    upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) =>{
                        addPost(snapshot);
                        console.log(snapshot);
                    })
            };

            const uploadError = snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot);
            };

            upload.on("state_changed", uploadProgress, uploadError, uploadComplete );

            
            };



        const addPost = (downloadURL) => {  
            firebase.firestore() 
            .collection("allPosts")
            .collection(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .add({
            
                downloadURL,
                name,
            }).then((function () {
                props.navigation.popToTop()
            }))
        } 


        useEffect(() => {
        const {params} = props.route;
        if(params) {
        const {photos} = params;
        if(photos) setPhotos(photos)
        delete params.photos
        }

        }, [{photos}]) // This useEffect updates when coming back from the ImageBrowserScreen (can be found in snack.io, it's exactly the same)
```

The main problem is, let's say, I choose 3 photos. If I console.log(photos) I get this:

```
  Array [
   Object {
    "name": "name1.JPG",
    "type": "image/jpg",
    "uri": "file:///name1.jpg",
   },
   Object {
    "name": "name2.JPG",
    "type": "image/jpg",
    "uri": "file:///name2.jpg",
   },
   Object {
    "name": "name3.JPG",
    "type": "image/jpg",
    "uri": "file:///name3.jpg",
   },
  ]
```

The only I could get it to work was this, give exact path to uri (photos[0].uri for example) otherwise get network error. But this only uploads the first object/photo. I also tried to map through the photos state and return all uri's into a single array and use that as const uri, but that obviously didn't work, for uri needs only one string. So I somehow need to run that function for each uri to be able to get a downloadURL and store each of them.

EDIT:

```
const uploadImage = async (photo) => {
const uri = photo.uri;
const childPath = `data/${
  firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
console.log(childPath);
const response = await fetch(uri);
const blob = await response.blob();

const snapshot = await firebase.storage().ref().child(childPath).put(blob);
const downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
imgs.push(downloadURL)
};

 const uploadPhotos = async () => {
  await Promise.all(photos.map(p=>uploadImage(photo)).then(addPost())
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it with a loop trough all photos and upload them separately. Idealy using a `Promise.all` to upload them in parallel:

```js
 const addPost = async (downloadURLs) => {  
            await firebase.firestore() 
            .collection("allPosts")
            .collection(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .add({
                downloadURLs,
                name,
            })
     props.navigation.popToTop()
        } 

  const uploadImage = async (photo) => {
    const uri = photo.uri;
    const childPath = `data/${
      firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    }/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
    console.log(childPath);
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const snapshot = await firebase.storage().ref().child(childPath).put(blob);
    const downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL
  };

  const uploadPhotos = async () => {
      const downloadURLs=await Promise.all(photos.map(p=>uploadImage(photo))

      await addPost(downloadURLs);
  };
```

Comment: Works great with uploading the files to storage, thanks! I encountered a problem on adding the actual post to firestore. From what I saw, if the addPost() is in uploadImage, it will run the function for each image (creating a post in firestore for each image) instead of one post, with all images in an array field. So I tried this: removed the addPost from uploadImage, instead, added it after the promise solves. And for each downloadURL in uploadImage, push it to an array state. But from my console.logs, I only get the downloadURL a few seconds after, and thus array is empty.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code that should also add the post properly.

Comment: I've tried it, still not working. Does the same, uploads a different post for each different downloadURL. I think the most optimal solution would be to add all downloadURLs into an array in frontend, and add that array to post. But as I said above, couldn't get it to work. I have to figure out a way to wait until all links are in the array, for now the array is sent empty to firestore.

Comment: I tought you want them to be saved separately. But you want to have a single `post` element you can save all DownloadURL as you said to a single array and add that array to  the post object. Or you can create the post object once and save the links in a nested part of it.

Comment: I've tried with the first approach, to push each downloadURL to an array, but as I said above, I couldn't get it to work, because addPost() grabs the array before the firebase manages to return the actual links, and thus the array is uploaded empty.

Comment: Can you try it with the code of the updated answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! Truly appreciate your help!